# How to run an existing Django application on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a Django application on AWS Ec2 instance. I've chosen Ubuntu as my platform. After cloning the git repository, and creating a virtual environment, I have installed all apps in my requirements.txt. When I try to the following lines of code `python3 manage.py migrate` ; `python3 manage.py check` ; `python3 manage.py runserver` the following error is coming up.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "columbus_db" connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "columbus_db"

My settings.py file looks like this

```
 DATABASES = {
# 'default': {
#     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
# }'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  # Database Engine of PostgreSQL Database
    'NAME': 'columbus_db',  # Database Name
    'USER': 'columbus_db',  # Database has a Root User
    'PASSWORD': 'columbus',  # Database Connection Password
    'HOST': "localhost",  # IP Address for Localhost
}
```

What can I change in settings.py or Ec2 Instance settings to start the application and see it at Ec2 IP address?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a running database, the app code except it to be PostgreSQL, you have multiple choices:

- Install and run a local PostgreSQL instance directly in your EC2
- Use Amazon's managed database RDS
- Use Sqlite which is simple to setup and doesn't require more configuration, but your app might required specific PostgreSQL features

Comment: I went with installing and running local PostgreSQL, and created a new role and database. when I try '\conninfo' It says 'You are connected to database "columbus_db" as user "columbus_db" via socket it "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432". But still the same error is coming up when I try to runserver.

Comment: @yslk Did you change the database password to `columbus` and enable password login?